# libavcodec/libfdk-aacenc.c error while compiling ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to install FFMPEG on my Raspeberry following this procedure: https://gist.github.com/adddog/d82581faf10d666d35b9771eaa65d5ac.

While doing this step of the procedure:

```
sudo apt-get install -y xserver-xorg-dev libxext-dev build-essential libxi-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libglew-dev
wget http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v9c.tar.gz
tar xvfz jpegsrc*
cd jpeg-9c
./configure --enable-shared --prefix=$CONFIGURE_PREFIX
make -j4
sudo make install
```

I'm getting this error while compiling:

```
libavcodec/libfdk-aacenc.c:289:34: error: ‘AACENC_InfoStruct {aka struct <anonymous>}’ has no member named ‘encoderDelay’; did you mean ‘nDelay’?
```

Can you please help me? Whithout solving this issue I cannot install FFMPEG at all.

Thanks,
Claudio

Answer (score 1):

## What is wrong

You're trying to install FFmpeg 3.4, which is old, with libfdk-aacenc from its master branch, which is new.

It appears there is an API break beginning with libfdk-aac v2. It has been fixed in since FFmpeg 4.0, but not backported to FFmpeg 3.4.

## How to fix

Use FFmpeg from the master branch, or try to at least use FFmpeg 4.2. Alternatively, use an old libfdk-aac version if you're stuck using FFmpeg 3.4.

## Removing the old ffmpeg

Since you removed the ffmpeg source code directory, and/or because you did not integrate the installation into your package management system (such as with `checkinstall`), you'll have to manually uninstall the ffmpeg files. One way to do that is to re-run the ffmpeg instructions and then run `sudo make uninstall`:

```
git clone --depth 1 -b release/3.4 https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg.git ffmpeg
cd ffmpeg
./configure --arch=armel --target-os=linux  --enable-libfdk-aac  --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-mmal --enable-omx --enable-omx-rpi --enable-decoder=h264_mmal --enable-decoder=mpeg2_mmal --enable-encoder=h264_omx --enable-encoder=h264_omx  --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-version3 --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads  --enable-runtime-cpudetect  --enable-openssl --bindir="/usr/local/bin"
make -j3
sudo make uninstall
```

## Install new ffmpeg

You can download a simple snapshot because you don't need to download the complete git history which is a waste of time and bandwidth (or add `--depth 1` to your `git` commands):

```
wget -O ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 https://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2
tar xjvf ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2
cd ffmpeg
```

Then continue with your `./configure`, `make`, `sudo make install`, etc.

Comment: Any idea which version of libfdk-aac to use for ffmpeg 3.4.8?

Comment: @Connor I'm guessing fdk-aac 0.1.6. But why use FFmpeg 3.4.8 instead of something not old?

Comment: Because the not old things aren't old enough to work on the old os versions I'm stuck with